# How to check in Swift if an iPhone supports NFC?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, nfc

I need to make a request from my code where one of the parameters is if the device supports NFC or not. I don't use the NFC capability in my app. I have tried

```
import CoreNFC

...

guard NFCNDEFReaderSession.readingAvailable
```

But this check fails for even supported devices. Is checking this way unsupported if there is no intention to use it in the app and is adding keys in entitlements and info plist the only way to go? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `NFCNDEFReaderSession.readingAvailable`

Comment: This doesn't work out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import CoreNFC
```

in viewDidLoad check if NFC is available:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
       if NFCNDEFReaderSession.readingAvailable {
        print("NFC is avaiable")
       }
       else {
        print("NFC is NOT avaiable")
       }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me as I mentioned in the question. Even trying on an iPhone 11 says NFC is not available. Which is why I doubt I must add the capability to the project even just to check if the device is NFC enabled.

Comment: @user2236862 ok, take a look here https://www.raywenderlich.com/9582458-getting-started-with-core-nfc